# Call to undefined function asset() in Laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to load my `app.js` file inside my `welcome.blade.php` but I get the following error:

> Call to undefined function  asset()

This is the instruction I used `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('public/js/app.js') }}"></script>`

What can be the problem? I also tried to run the same line without `asset()` and it does not work. My .js file is in the location I specified.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you been modifying which files get loaded by the composer autoloader in any way?

Comment: I do not think so. Actually I tried to load it with blade: `{ { Html::script('public/js/app.js')  }} ` and it seems like it does not recognize the Blade syntax either.

Comment: Can you try using `asset('public/app.js')` from `php artisan tinker` and say if it works?

Answer (score 1):

**Process:**

I am using Laravel 5.5 and had the same problem recently so I did a bit of debugging. Here are the steps:

1. Since the error was `Call to undefined function asset()` I checked the `helpers.php` in the Laravel repo to see if it existed. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L127 and it did.

   ```
   if (! function_exists('asset')) {
       /**
        * Generate an asset path for the application.
        *
        * @param  string  $path
        * @param  bool    $secure
        * @return string
        */
       function asset($path, $secure = null)
       {
           return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
       }
   }
   ```
2. I looked on my local copy of Laravel and see if that same line existed, it did.
3. However my local copy was different than what was on the repo. This is how it looked:

   ```
   if (! function_exists('asset')) {
       /**
        * Generate an asset path for the application.
        *
        * @param  string  $path
        * @param  bool    $secure
        * @return string
        */
       function mixasset($path, $secure = null)
       {
           return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
       }
   }
   ```
4. At some point, Laravel Mix seems to have changed `asset()` to `mixasset()`.

---

**Result:**

Try using `mixasset()` as opposed to `asset()`. Otherwise delete your `vendors` folder and rebuild it by running `composer install`. This should get you the latest copy of your Laravel version with the correct `asset()` helper method.

Answer (score 0):

The `asset()` is already point to your public folder so, don't specify the public in your `asset()` 
Change your `asset('public/js/app.js')` to `asset('js/app.js')`

Comment: It does not change anything :(

Comment: The asset function is undefined, changing its params won't do much.

Answer (score 0):

My Err: Call to undefined function set_active()...., when I move some functions in Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 6.x ...
My solution:
1. Added below in composer.json
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php" . => New added
        ]
}
2.run composer install
it works for me.